# Does it make sense to talk about a frequency when we deal with damped oscillations?

Tags: waves, friction, frequency, oscillators, dissipation

I'm solving a problem in which there is a damping force in the form $F = -bv$.
The question asks for the "frequency of oscillation", but since it is a damped oscillation I am confused, because I think that in this case one can't define a value for the frequency.

Comment: If the damping is small there is still an oscillation but its amplitude is contained within an exponentially decaying envelope.

Comment: Have you been taught about complex frequencies yet? What exactly does the question mean by frequency?  One can *always* ascribe a meaningful frequency to an arbitrarily damped system by a number of definitions, even if it is overdamped. However, in the the overdamped or critically damped case, there are no "wiggles" to see in the response, even though frequency, somewhat abstractly, is still defined.

Answer (score 2):

## If the motion is being driven

Well, after dividing by various constants your differential equation is going to look like:
$$ \ddot f + 2\lambda \dot f + \omega_0^2 f = g(t).$$
If $g(t) = A \cos(\Omega t)$ for example, then you will find that $f(t)$ has (angular) frequency $\Omega$ as well. This is easiest to see under a Fourier transform, $$f[\omega] = \frac{g[\omega]}{-\omega^2 + 2i \lambda\omega + \omega_0^2}.$$ We can treat cosines and sines via the Dirac $\delta$-function, and we find that the inverse transform for  $g[\omega] = \delta(\omega - \Omega)$ is going to be $$f(t) = \frac{e^{i\Omega t}}{-\Omega^2 + 2i\lambda\Omega + \omega_0^2}.$$ The term on the bottom describes a phase shift and amplitude rescaling due to $\Omega$ being on or off the resonance peak; the term on the top says that it oscillates with the driving frequency $\Omega$ regardless.

## If the motion is not being driven

Of course the above are "particular solutions" $f_P$ and to use them you also need the "homogeneous solution" $f_H$ to the equation
$$ \ddot f + 2\lambda \dot f + \omega_0^2 f = 0.$$Then you will see that the general solution is $f = f_P + f_H$ due to the linearity of derivatives. But there is a trick very similar to the Fourier transform which is to just assume that $f(t) = A~e^{st}$ for some $s$. In this case we get $$s^2 + 2\lambda s + \omega_0^2 = 0$$which we can solve to find $s = -\lambda \pm \sqrt{\lambda^2 - \omega_0^2}$.

This also has an interpretation as having an oscillation with a special frequency, if $\lambda^2 < \omega_0^2.$ Let $\tilde\omega^2 = \omega_0^2 - \lambda^2$ be a positive number, then this trick tells us that our homogeneous solution family looks like, $$f_H(t) = A e^{-\lambda t} e^{i\tilde\omega t} + B e^{-\lambda t} e^{-i\tilde\omega t}. $$ You can recast this as you like; for example $A e^{-\lambda t} \cos(\tilde\omega t + \varphi)$ works.

In any case, we can clearly see that the sinusoidal part of an "underdamped" system oscillates with frequency $\tilde\omega = \sqrt{\omega_0^2 - \lambda^2}$, but it does go to zero in an exponential "envelope." This $\tilde \omega$ could also be a reasonable definition of the frequency of the damped oscillator.

Answer (score 1):

The period of oscillation can be defined from the times at which the oscillator passes through the equilibrium position. This assumes that it does so several times - ie the damping is significantly less than the critical value. It is harder to identify or measure the period from the maxima or minima, since the amplitude is constantly decreasing.

The frequency measured between zero-crossings is slightly less than the natural (undamped) frequency, but for a damped harmonic oscillator (restoring force proportional to displacement) it remains constant as the amplitude of oscillation decreases. This is not quite the case for the simple pendulum because the restoring force is not strictly proportional to displacement; it is not because of the damping.

The underdamped frequency is $\omega_1=\sqrt{\omega_0^2-\gamma^2}$ where $\omega_0$ is the natural frequency and $\gamma=b/2m$ is the decay constant. See Eqn #71 on the [Farside Physics website](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/315/Waves/node10.html).

Comment: sammy gerbil, how can I calculate the frequency for a dumped oscillation then?  I would like to prove that it does not change over time. Thank you.

Comment: @Victor https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_oscillator#Damped_harmonic_oscillator Explains key points of damped harmonic oscillation in a simple yet detailed enough way I'd say.

Comment: I've read it, I still do not get what should I compute to answer what is the "frequency."

Comment: @Victor It does explicitly say how to determine the frequency of the underdamped harmonic oscillator.  I don't really think it's beneficial for me or for you if I tell you exactly what it is.  Research is a useful tool, and I pointed you exactly where you need to look.

Comment: The usual calculation that keeps the damped oscillator (pseudo-)frequencey independent of amplitude assumes the damping is proportional to velocity. I think that other dissipative  regimes don't necessarily have that isochronic property.

Answer (score 1):

Damped simple harmonic motion comes in three flavors: "light", "critical", and "heavy". A lightly damped system will oscillate (with a frequency close to the undamped resonance frequency). See this diagram:

[image]

Clearly, lightly damped motion has a frequency.

If the equation of motion is of the form

$$\ddot x + \beta \dot x + \omega_0^2 x = 0$$

Then when $\beta = 2\omega_0$, you have critical damping. If it is less, you have light damping; if it's greater, you have heavy damping.

See for example [Wolfram Alpha article on critical damping](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CriticallyDampedSimpleHarmonicMotion.html)

Comment: Does the critically damped oscillator overshoot the equilibrium position? I used to think it did but the [Hyperphysics website](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/oscda2.html#c1) says not, and I've corrected my answer to another question. Or perhaps in your simulation the oscillator is started with an impulse?

Comment: @sammygerbil - the critically damped oscillator has at most one zero crossing - you get this by giving it an appropriate impulse towards zero.

Comment: The equation of motion is of the form $ x = (A+Bt)e^{-t/\tau}$; when A*B<0 you get a zero crossing.

Comment: It's a little unusual to show the critical case with the overshoot and not show it for the overdamped case as well. It is, after all, still possible with overdamping though you need an even bigger initial push toward equilibrium (to a ridiculous degree if the system can be described as "heavily damped", but still...).

Comment: Typically, it is the *step response* (rather than impulse response) that is used to display the under-, critically-, and over-damped cases.  In that case, the critically-damped case shows the fastest rise time without overshoot, [for example](http://support.motioneng.com/Utilities/bode/images/bode_72_timedamping.gif)

Answer (score 0):

When there is damping, your *energy* is being dissipated. The energy of the system is not represented by frequency. What is happening is that your amplitude is reducing, and your frequency remains the same. Hence yes, it does make sense to talk about frequency.

Comment: I'd like to add that, as ZeroTheHero explained, such a case exists when damping is small.

Comment: I think it's actually safe to exclude that caveat as long as it's clear we're talking about damped _oscillations_.  A "damped harmonic oscillator" doesn't actually "oscillate" if it's over/critically damped.  When damping is large, you're no longer oscillating, so the whole question would be moot.  Pretty pedantic and perhaps confusing; but the nomenclature was working in your favour here.

Comment: @JMac It's not really confusing at all.  If an eigenvalue of the unforced motion of the system is complex, the imaginary part measures the frequency and the real part the damping. (Note, damped vibration is not restricted to 1-DOF systems!) If the eigenvalue is real, there is no oscillation. But for *undamped* vibration, people rewrite the equation of motion so you have a first order eigenvalue problem not a second order one, the frequencies then come out as *real* numbers, not pure imaginary ones. (The notion of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie-to-children springs to mind here...)

Comment: @VitorCGoergen Such cases also exist when the damping is negative (i.e. the system is *gaining* energy because of its motion). (There are real-life engineering devices where that happens - I'm not talking woo-woo about perpetual motion machines or "free energy.")